# Usar str.split() para seleccionar partes de una cadena separando por espacios consecutivos

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estoy recibiendo unas lineas de log, a las cuales les genero una cabecera con los datos de algunos de los campos, como la primera ip en la linea.

Para ello utilice un split de espacios vacíos y así pude seleccionar la información que quería utilizar en la cabecera.

Pero me he dado cuenta que cuando el día del log es inferior a 10 en vez de escribirse el número con un cero delante, se genera otro espacio vacío y el script falla, ya que, en vez de seleccionar la ip, selecciona la hora.

Por ejemplo, dadas estas dos lineas con distinta fecha:

> <7>Feb 28 20:06:09 113.78.60.60 1,2013/06/02 00:04:03,891701036531,sunny,0,
>
> <7>Feb  8 20:06:09 113.78.60.60 1,2013/06/02 00:04:03,891701036531,sunny,0,

Al usar el siguiente código:

```
import sys
import time

Log = sys.stdin.readline()
Ip = Log.split(' ')[3]

print Ip + ',' + Log
```

con la primera cadena se captura la *Ip* sin problemas ("113.78.60.60") pero con la segunda lo que se obtiene es la hora ("20:06:09").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si especificas a `str.split` que parta la cadena cada vez que encuentra un espacio hace exactamente eso:

```
>>> log = "<7>Feb  8 20:06:09 113.78.60.60 1"
>>> log.split(" ")
['<7>Feb', '', '8', '20:06:09', '113.78.60.60', '1']
```

Lo que quieres es que parta la cadena siempre que encuentre un espacio o cualquier número de espacios consecutivos. Curiosamente esto lo hace la función `str.split` por defecto:

```
>>> log = "<7>Feb  8 20:06:09 113.78.60.60 1"
>>> log.split()
['<7>Feb', '8', '20:06:09', '113.78.60.60', '1']
```

Simplemente no le pases el argumento `sep`.

[Documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

Traducción libre:

> Si `sep` no se especifica o es `None`, se aplica un algoritmo de división diferente: los espacios en blanco consecutivos se consideran como un solo separador y el resultado no contendrá cadenas vacías al comienzo o al final si la cadena tiene espacios en blanco iniciales o finales.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Lo probare!

Comment: Comprobado! y funcionando. Gracias de nuevo!